# Yocto: ARCHIVER_MODE[src] = "configured" leads to ERROR ...crtprec32.o is installed by both libgcc and libgcc-initial

Tags: yocto

when i try to do an ordinary yocto-quick-build (qemu, core-image-minimal), with
**dunfell release** and the following settings in the local.conf:

```
INHERIT += "archiver"
ARCHIVER_MODE[src] = "configured"`
```

I get the following Error message:

```
ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs:The file  /usr/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/9.3.0
/crtprec32.o is installed by both libgcc and ibgcc-initial, aborting
```

Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this issue ?